# Compiler error when using AlwaysRightInstitute/SwiftSockets

Tags: sockets, swift

I'm try to write a small game on IOS using socket and I've had a java socket server running with Flash client, but I got complier errors when I add the AlwaysRightInstitute/SwiftSockets source code to my swift project, and I did nothing after doing this

Here is the project structure:

[image]

the selected group "ARISockets" is the source code I drag into my project

and here are the errors(Use of unresolved identifier 'ari_fcntIVi'):

[image]

It seems that the errors cause by lack of some import file and I found "ari_fcntIVi" in ARISockets/UnixBridge.c,but I'm a really newer to Swift/Objective-C/C (I'm a AS3 developer), so that sucks me :/

Comment: Try adding an include `ARISockets.h` to your bridging header.

Comment: I add #include "AISockets.h" to UnixBridge.c but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this library.
You need to create a Bridge file similar to "Import Objective-C into Swift"  but this is C:

[How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that you just copied over the sources instead of embedding the SwiftSockets framework. The ari_ prefixed functions used to required the bridging header of the SwiftSockets framework.

Having said that, the current [SwiftSockets](http://www.alwaysrightinstitute.com/SwiftSockets/) doesn't use bridging headers anymore, and you can directly embed the sources.